# web service to retrieve image from database using linQ

Tags: c#, ajax, linq

i`m writing this code where i want to make a web service to retrieve an image from database ..

and using this web service in the ajax code

any help ?

thanks

```
    [WebMethod]
public List<BabyProfile> SelectPicOfBaby()
{
    BabyCareeEntities bc = new BabyCareeEntities();
    var query = (from s in bc.BabyProfiles
                 where  s.Image
                 select s).ToList<BabyProfile>();



    return query;


    //var quary1 = (from s in nw.Employees
    //             where s.EmployeeID == 1
    //             select s).ToList<Employee>();

}
```

Comment: Use .Single() instead of .ToList()

Comment: @StefanoAltieri I don't think that this is solution... he wants to retrieve an image not an object list. I wonder what is a `Image` property, is it an image url? Anyway the question he is asking is unclear at least for me.

Comment: why dont you describe the problem?

Comment: I want to create a webservice  to retrieve an image from the table `BabyProfiles`

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the `Image` property from whatever `BabyProfiles` gets you? - (I suppose it's a `BabyProfile` list)

If you really want it then try this:

```
var query = (from s in bc.BabyProfiles
    select s.Image).ToList();
```

Anyway your question is rather unclear cause I'm not 100% sure what you are asking us to help you.